# Kafka producer sending null key instead of string

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit, kafka-producer-api

I am using a Producer to send messages to a Kafka topic.

When JUnit testing, I have found that the producer in my application code (but not in my JUnit test class) is sending a null key, despite me providing a String key for it to use.

Code as follows:

Main application class

```java
final Producer<String, HashSet<String>> actualApplicationProducer;

ApplicationInstance(String bootstrapServers) // constructor
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "ActualClient");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, lingerBatchMS);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, Math.min(maxBatchSizeBytes,1000000));

    actualApplicationProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
}

public void doStuff()
{
    HashSet<String> values = new HashSet<String>();
    String key = "applicationKey";
    // THIS LINE IS SENDING A NULL KEY
    actualApplicationProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, key, values));
}
```

But, in my junit classes:

```java
@EmbeddedKafka
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SuppressWarnings("static-method")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class CIFFileProcessorTests 
{
    /** An Embedded Kafka Broker that can be used for unit testing purposes. */
    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

@BeforeAll
    public void setUpBeforeClass(@TempDir File globalTablesDir, @TempDir File rootDir) throws Exception 
    {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "JUnitClient");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, lingerBatchMS);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, Math.min(maxBatchSizeBytes,1000000));
        try(Producer<String, HashSet<String>> junitProducer = new Producer<>(props))
        {
            HashSet<String> values = new HashSet<>();
            // Here, I'm sending a record, just like in my main application code, but it's sending the key correctly and not null
            junitProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,"junitKey",values));
        }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        ApplicationInstance sut = new ApplicationInstance(embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokersAsString());
sut.doStuff();
        
        // "records" is a LinkedBlockingQueue, populated by a KafkaMessageListenerContainer which is monitoring the topic for records using a MessageListener
        ConsumerRecord<String, HashSet<String>> record = records.poll(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertEquals("junitKey", record.key()); // TEST FAILS - expected "junitKey" but returned null
    }
```

Custom serializer:

```java
try (final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) 
        {
            oos.writeObject(object);
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
```

Does anyone know why the `KafkaProducer` would send a null key when I explicitly specify a String?

--- Update ---

I have tried inspecting the metadata, and the Producer is indeed sending the key, and not null:

```java
RecordMetadata info = actualApplicationProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, key, values)).get(); 
System.out.println("INFO - partition: " + info.partition() + ", topic: " + info.topic() + ", offset: " + info.offset() + ", timestamp: "+ info.timestamp() + ", keysize: " + info.serializedKeySize() + ", valuesize: " + info.serializedValueSize());
```

output:

> INFO - partition: 0, topic: topicName, offset: 2, timestamp: 1656060840304, keysize: 14, valuesize: 6258

The keysize being > 0 shows that null is not passed to the topic.

So, the issue must be with the reading of the topic, perhaps?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should try not to use `ObjectOutputStream` if you plan on having non-Java consumers (which is common when using Kafka)

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the heads up, I'll investigate that - but you're right, I think it's unrelated to the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, I was using a different Deserializer class for my `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`, which didn't know what to do with the String as provided

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you want to use ByteArrayOutputStream or ObjectOutputStream for serializing KAFKA producer records, that may be your requirement. In such case, you may refer the producer section from https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-producer-and-consumer-example

But injecting key in the producer record can be easily done. For example, if you want generate a Producer Record from an AVRO schema and use assert to inject record key and value, you can do something like this.

1. Generate a AVRO or Specific records

You can refer https://technology.amis.nl/soa/kafka/generate-random-json-data-from-an-avro-schema-using-java/

You can convert it to SpecifiRecords using JSONAVROConverter:

```
public static ProducerRecord<String, CustomEvent> generateRecord(){
    String schemaFile = "AVROSchema.avsc";
    Schema schema = getSchema(JSONFile);
    String json = getJson(dataFile);

    byte[] jsonBytes = json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    CustomEventMessage producerRecord = null;
    JsonAvroConverter converter = new JsonAvroConverter();

    try {

        record = converter.convertToSpecificRecord(jsonBytes, CustomEvent.class, schema);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    String recordKey = "YourKey";

    return new ProducerRecord<String, CustomEvent>( topic, recordKey, record);
}
```

2. You can inject the ProducerRecord into your Assert functions later.

Comment: I'm sorry but, interesting though this is, I don't see the relevance to my issue - I am providing the key in the ProducerRecord in both cases, but in one case Kafka (or something) is converting it to null, and in the other case it's working as expected